# C#: How can I write a combination of text and binary data to a file?

Tags: c#

My people need me to output a file with a combination of text strings (with each character stored as a 2-digit hex value) and ushorts (with each 16-bit ushort stored as a 4-digit hex value).

I was trying to do this with `StreamWriter`, but each number gets written to the file digit-by-digit...  So for example, a value of 257 gets written as 32 35 37.  I need it to be written as 01 01.

Maybe I can use `StreamWriter` and `BinaryWriter` to write to the same file?  I haven't been able to figure this out though...

Any ideas?

Comment: " a value of 257 gets written as 32 35 37. I need it to be written as 01 01". What??? Why?

Comment: Use a BinaryWriter, it has both WriteInt32 and WriteString

Comment: @Oded That's the hexadecimal representation of 257 on a short.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`BinaryWriter` and `.WriteChars(...)` and `.WriteUInt##(...);`

Comment: Great, works..  I didn't realize BinaryWriter worked that way!  This is the first time I ever used it..  Thanks!